# CMake: define custom include path

Tags: c, cmake

I need to include ZIMPL in a CMake project. In the source code the ZIMPL headers are included like this

```
#include zimpl/bool.h
```

The actual path within ZIMPL is `zimpl/src/bool.h`. How can I tell CMake (or the C linker) to look in `zimpl/src/` whenever it encounters a `zimpl/` include?
I would prefer to avoid creating symlinks for the sake of platform independence.

Comment: "duplicated" question asks how to write CMake script if files hierarchy **already have** needed relative paths. Given question *explicitely says* that relative paths in `#include` **differ** from one in files hierarchy. Voted for reopen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot `#include` files using relative path different from actual one.

The simples way to do with your case is to copy original headers into locations, which has needed path suffixes. It can be done with CMake via `file(COPY)` or `configure_file(.. COPY_ONLY)`:

```
file(COPY <source_include_dir>/zimpl/src/bool.h
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/include/zimple/
)
include_directories(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/include)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do so with the [`include_directories()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/include_directories.html) command. It takes a list of directories for its arguments.

Comment: Yes, I know. But since the include command in the C source code demands the specific path ```zimpl/bool.h```, it is not found - although the respective ```src/``` directory is included by CMake.

Comment: Oh, you mean remapping `zimpl/bool.h` to `zimpl/src/bool.h`? You can't do that because include paths are just root directories for the compiler to search in. So if root is, say, `zimpl/src/`, you have to include it as `<bool.h>`. I'd recommend making a separate `include/zimpl` directory, instead.